# How to make OrbitControls work with 8thWall Web using ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I have integrated the [Basic Tap to Place example](https://github.com/8thwall/web/tree/master/examples/threejs/placeground) of 8th Wall using ThreeJS and entred some modifications on it, now I am trying to add Pinch Zoom and Rotation feature to the Augmented Scene/Object I tried to follow every ThreeJS tutorial but when it comes to working with 8thWall I can't figure out a way to work it out. I would appreciate it if someone could confirm if this is possible and how? my struggle was always that ThreeJS Camera is manipulated by 8thWall.

Answer (score 0):

8th Wall controls the position/rotation of the three.js camera as you move your phone around in the real world. OrbitControls allows the camera to orbit around a target, so these two things aren't going to play nicely together.

A better approach would be to move/rotate/scale the scene content itself.

See https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/manipulate-aframe for a simple example of this.